# Can't update value: 'Primary Key' has a temporary value while attempting to change the entity's state to 'Modified'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

This is my first **ASP .Net Core** project. It will hold directors. Each director has a page that shows a list of his/her movies.

I have two classes.
**Movie**:

```
public class Movie
    {
        public int MovieId { get; private set; }
        public int DirectorId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

And **Director**:

```
public class Director
    {
        public Director()
        {
            Movies = new List<Movie>();
        }
        public int DirectorId { get; private set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Bio { get; set; }
        public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }
```

But I have a problem with editing Directors. As I want to save changes I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: The property 'DirectorId' on entity type
>   'Director' has a temporary value while attempting to change the
>   entity's state to 'Modified'. Either set a permanent value explicitly
>   or ensure that the database is configured to generate values for this
>   property.

I use this line of code in Index page to navigate to Edit page:

```
<a asp-page="./../Movies/Create" asp-route-DirectorId="@item.DirectorId">Add Movie</a>
```

Photo of Index page:
[Please click to see the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bB5mx.png)

---

The code in **Edit.cshtml.cs**:

```
public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly MastersOfCinema.Data.Context _context;

    public EditModel(MastersOfCinema.Data.Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public Director Director { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? directorId)
    {
        if (directorId == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        Director = await _context.Director.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.DirectorId == directorId);

        if (Director == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Page();
    }

    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
    // more details, see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _context.Attach(Director).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!DirectorExists(Director.DirectorId))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }

    private bool DirectorExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.Director.Any(e => e.DirectorId == id);
    }
}
```

Apparently, Something upsets this very line:

```
_context.Attach(Director).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Perhaps it is about the primary key (DirectorId), As the error suggests.

Edit page screenshot:
[Please Click to see Edit page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHbJb.png)

---

**Edit.cshtml** :

```
@page
@model MastersOfCinema.Pages.Directors.EditModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h1>Edit</h1>

<h4>Director</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Director.DirectorId" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Director.DirectorId" class="form-control" />

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Director.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Director.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Director.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Director.Country" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Director.Country" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Director.Country" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Director.Bio" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Director.Bio" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Director.Bio" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-page="./Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

---

Additional information:

**Context.cs** (Uses EF Core) :

```
public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public Context (DbContextOptions<Context> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<MastersOfCinema.Models.Director> Director { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MastersOfCinema.Models.Movie> Movie { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
                "Data Source = (localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = MastersOfCinama");
        }


    }
```

Thanks for reading and for any help.

Comment: If you're adding a new one, you have to use context EntityState.Added, not Modified. If you're not adding it, use Find or something to get the existing entity from the context before setting state to Modified, or look up its PK and set it.I'm a bit new to EF too though, so someone correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: @Nikki9696 I can add a new one and it works. The problem is about editing. I fetch the existing row and I can see its values. So I wonder why I get an error when I click on the save button.
See this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHbJb.png
I appreciate your help anyway.

Comment: Well, I haven't tried the way you're doing with Attach, but it works with my little EF project where I just grab from the context for edits and add to the context for adds. I don't set the state at all, it knows. I use MyDbContext.MyEntityName.Add(object) or MyDbContext.MyEntityName.Find(key), set the changes and Update, and savechanges.

Comment: @Nikki9696 I will try with your advice again. But I am very new to programming and I'm afraid I need more exact solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the private setter from:

```
public int DirectorId { get; private set; }
```

Instead it should look like this:

```
public int DirectorId { get; set; }
```